A predicate as argument of a predicate
In Dependency Grammar we consider the meaning of a wordform either as a semantic predicate (:=predicate) or as a semantic name. Let us suppose we have a predicate, which has a predicate as argument (e.g. in 'He speaks Danish well' we have speaks=speaks(He,Danish) and well=well(speaks)). The questions are
a. How does this perspective agree with Predicate Calculus (where a predicate cannot be argument of another predicate)?
b. Has some suitable to this occasion Calculus been developed?
c. What about the negation operation in a Calculus as in (b)? What would happen in a case as P(~Q(x)), where P,Q predicates and x a term? Would it be equal to ~P?
ADDENDUM
At A. Polguere, I. Mel'cuk, Dependency in Linguistic Description, p.10 we read: "[...] the meaning of a sentence can be represented using the formalism of the predicate calculus. We say that an argument of a predicate semantically depends on this predicate; for P(a) we write P–sem→a. As I have said, an argument of a predicate P_1 can be another predicate P_2 with its own arguments [...]". (This book is just great as all Mel'cuk's works.) Here the author treats the idea of predicate-inside-predicate absolutely naturally. Furthermore he makes straight reference to predicate calulus!

@Lambie I am really trying to understand what do you mean by this comment.

@Lambie That's like saying "Probability is not medicine, it's from statistics" when someone asks what model best accounts for the risk factors of a certain disease. The question is about how to describe a certain linguistic phenomenon employing a mathematical tool.

... and not how predicate logic itself works, so it is not a question about logic.

"an argument of a predicate P_1 can be another predicate P_2 with its own arguments" - Not in formal predicate calculus. In first-order calculus not anyway, but even with predicates of higher order, the argument would have to be a predicate P_1(P_2), and not an application of a predicate to arguments P_1(P_2(x)).

@NatalieClarius This is exactly the root of my questioning; either a new Logic is rising or this fragment has false meaning (or no meaning at all).

PS. Is there a way to continue this discussion in chat? I think that there are many things to be added. If someone could help, it would be great.

In Jerry Hobbs’ framework (based on FOL) there’s reification of pretty much everything, including embedded and complex predicates. It neatly reflects all the dependencies in an utterance. There are also computational models for it.

@Atamiri Could you cite about that?

@SK_ The principles are well explained here: https://www.isi.edu/people-hobbs/research-areas/encoding-commonsense-knowledge/

You are correct that predicates of predicates, in particular adverbs like "well", are not straightforwardly translated into (first-order) predicate calculus, as something like P(Q(x)) or P(Q) would simply not be a well-formed formula.
A way to solve this problem (and more) is so-called event calculus, where you amend the core predicate with an individual argument that stands for the event on which the action occurred, and the adverb can then be an additional property (predicate) of this event:

"John buttered the bread slowly"


= "There is an event which is a buttering event between John and the bread and which happend slowly"


∃e(Butter(j, b, e) ∧ Slow(e))

Your example could similarly be rephrased as

∃e(Speak(x,d,e) ∧ Well(e))

It's not great in this case because the speaking would be understood to be a permanent property of John rather than a temporarily occurring event, but you get the idea. One could apply a similar trick with a concept such as states instead of events that may be more suitable for this example.
With events added we're still in the realm of first order logic, so negation proceeds as usual (namely on formulas, not on predicates). It would be ~∃e(Speak(x,d,e) ∧ Well(e)) or ∃e(Speak(x,d,e) ∧ ~Well(e)), depending on which meaning is intended.
You can read more about it in chapter 11 here.

Τhank you for your answer (+1).  I would insist as such: do you think that the formalization of Dependency Semantics would be Event Calculus? No Higher Order like approach would formalize it? Additionally the negation of the last rephrase is as I can imagine (i.d. for all e (~Speak or ~Well))?

No, I don't see it particularly related to dependency grammar. If anything, this formalization maps more closely to a traditional tree structure, as in the the formalization syntactically the adverb predication is a sister to the verb predication rather than in each other's scope. I have to admit I haven't seen a formal semantics on the basis of dependency grammar yet.

Higher order formalizations can express properties of properties which makes sense for things such as "red is a color", but here we want the adverb to be a property of the particular occasion of prediction with the specific subject and object arguments and not a property of speaking in general, so the event formalization maps closer to the meaning than what second order predicates could do

Re. negation: Edited my answer.

Natalie, I find it strange that negation could operate as above. In First Order case we 'd have ~(exists x (P(x) and Q(x)) equivalent to forall x(~P(x) or ~Q(x)). There above negation does  affect neither conjunction nor first predicate. Is it fine?! (I haven't seen this kind of logic and I wonder!)

About First Order and trees; provided that trees are n-ary relations (i.e. subsets of A^n, where A a non empty set) and n-ary relations can be considered as n-ary predicates (of the form P(a_1,...,a_n)), I think that we could still think about the possibility of using somehow First Order Logic on Dependency trees.

Re. Negation: What you say is correct, and nothing special is going on here, both are ordinary formulas of FOL. The second formalization I gave just expresses a different meaning. Putting negation in front means more unspecifically "It is not the case that he speaks Danish well (either doesn't speak it at all or not well); putting negation further in means "He speaks Danish but not well".

May well be that there is a first-order logic based compositional semantics for dependency grammar, I'm just not aware of one, and saying that introducing the notion of events on top of FOL isn't really something specifically relating to DG.

I agree that a formal semantics compatible with DG structures has not been developed. N-ary branching is the sticking point. Function application as it is generally understood applies to only one argument at a time, forcing the tree structures to admit binary branching only. This strict binarity of branching is, then, incompatible with the n-ary branching of dependency trees.

My preferred DG analysis of the example in the question, though, would be to view both speaks and well as predicates: well (speaks). But then the two words together form a single complex predicate such that we have: speaks well (he, Danish). In the dependency structure, speaks and well form a catena,(i.e. a subtree) and as such they qualify as a concrete unit of dependency structures. Thus, I would advocate a formal semantics that combines catenae as opposed to constituents.

@TimOsborne About the first comment; I think I haven' t understood why the n-arity causes problem in development of a strict DG formalization. What do you mean by "Function...time"? About the second; I strongly prefer the view of maximal division of elements inside a sentence (in any Structure, so in SemS too and mainly) -even interventing the periphrastic wordforms. The reason is that this way the passage from meaning to sentence is more radical and complete. Given this approach we can choose then any accepted combination of our Structure's elements that helps our respective purposes.

Most works in formal semantics assume a strict one-to-one mapping of units of meaning to units of syntax, and vice versa. The units of syntax are necessarily constituents, though, because there is no other unit of meaning that phrase structure could acknowledge in this area. Thus the predicates and arguments of logical analysis need to be recognizable as constituents in the syntactic structures one assumes. If they are not, then phrase structure syntax cannot pursue a plausible account of the manner in which meaning is mapped to structure.

The assumption that units of meaning can and must be mapped to constituents only is part of what has motivated the strictly binary branching phrase structures that are so prevalent among formal semanticists. Dependency grammar cannot pursue an analogous account of the semantics-syntax mapping because its syntactic structures are so minimal, acknowledging many fewer constituents. I think this is in fact an area where someone could make their mark. If a plausible DG theory of the semantics-syntax interface were developed, that would push DG ahead.

Concerning Mel'cuk's semantic dependencies cited in the addendum to the question, that account does not consider the manner in which meaning is mapped to units of syntax. Mel'cuk's semantic level of representation is abstract. His account does not acknowledge predicates and their arguments as concrete units of actual sentence structures. I have in fact asked Mel'cuk about this directly. He stated unequivocally that his predicates exist at a semantic level of representation only.

@TimOsborne Thank you for your interest but I think I have lost the common spirit of discussion. I just note that I am talking about semantics, semantic structures, semantic predicates, and their possible connection with a kind of Logic  (existing or not).

Right. The issue is dense and difficult., but interesting and very much worth scrutiny  Good luck.

@NatalieClarius Glue semantics works well with dependency grammars.

@SK_ There’s no problem with polyadicity (“n-arity”), in fact it meshes well with dependency-based syntax. There are various approaches such as glue semantics but any FOL-based approach could be used.

@Atamiri I think no one claimed that there is a problem with the number of arguments. Our problem is a predicate inside a predicate.

@SK_ That’s not a problem either, you use either reification and eventualities (the Davidsonian approach) or something like simple type theory which is higher-order (and complete with general semantics).

@NatalieClarius What about well(speak(he, Danish))? It seems closer to a DG semantic approach, provided that we use something like a "functional predicate" for our semantic predicate.

@SK_ What's a "functional predicate"?

@Atamiri In essence a functional predicate is just a function symbol, which means that a structure (~an interpretation) corresponds that to a function in common mathematical sense. However I was thinking of  using this name for semantic predicate in order to raise two things: a. an n-ary s-pred. maps n ordered semantemes to a semanteme (functional dimension), b. the functional symbol f can be seen as a property F (predicate dimension). But in essence we are talking about an n-ary operation.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
